# Problems connecting to Netgear DGN1000

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, wireless, netgear

I've just moved house. In my old house we had a Virgin Media "super hub", and all my devices connected fine.
We now have a Netgear DGN1000 and my laptops have trouble connnecting;

- One laptop is a Samsung, running 12.04, using the `wl` driver.
- The other is an ASUS, running 12.10, using the `iwlwifi` driver.
- Both devices have difficulty connecting. They sometimes connect sporadically, but are very slow (1-2 seconds to ping another device on the LAN) and drop connection before too long.
- Wired connections work fine
- We've got 3 Android devices which all work fine over wireless
- The Samsung also has Windows 7, which works fine
- Changing the channel of the Wifi seems to help, but it doesn't completely solve the problem (and has never been necessary before, even in a built-up area with lots of other networks nearby)

For a reason I can't explain, this seems to be Ubuntu-specific. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There might be a problem with your router's wifi channel. Try to change it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu. This field is used for actual answers. Your answer does not contain any valuable information on how to solve this issue. You might consider leaving a comment in the future unless you know an exact solution.

Comment: @donschoe "Half answers" like this are actually [much better as answers than as comments](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2281/please-stop-posting-half-answers-and-dumb-advice-as-comments). Also, this user [could not have commented](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @EliahKagan okay, understood. thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: That may have been too hasty. Both laptops now connect, but the connection is still flakey on the ASUS.